# How to parse this XML file URL, why I'm getting this error?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, foreach

I'm trying to parse this XML file but I'm getting this error:

**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 13**

Is the xml wrong or am I missing something?

The XML:

```
<ads>
<ad>
<id>
<![CDATA[ 9009394 ]]>
</id>
<address>
<![CDATA[ NewYork ]]>
</address>
<calle_nro>
<![CDATA[ 345 ]]>
</calle_nro>
</ad>
<ads>
```

The PHP script:

```
<?php
  print '<table style="width:80%"><tr>
    <th>Nro</th>
    <th>link</th> </tr>';


$html   = file_get_contents("http://gvaonline.com.ar/eti/eti.xml");

$feed = simplexml_load_string($html);

foreach ($feed->ads->ad as $item) {


  $linkTit  = $item->address;
  $imgLink  = $item->calle_nro;
  echo '<tr>';

  echo '<td>' . $linkTit . '</td>';
  echo '<td> '. $imgLink .'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';


}

  echo '</table>';

?>
```

I also try with the `simplexml_load_file()` and the url inside, but got the same problem with the foreach().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your example it looks like your XML is invalid, but I'm guessing that's just because you've typed it in,

You're final xml tag should be:

```
</ads>
```

As for your error it looks like it's because you're iterating through the XML object incorrectly.

An easy way to debug in the future is to print_r($feed), this is the output it gives:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [ad] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [id] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [address] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [calle_nro] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

        )
)
```

So going by that you should be doing:

```
foreach ($feed->ad as $item) {
```

instead of

```
foreach ($feed->ads->ad as $item) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you have cdata in your xml so use the right syntax in parsing.

something like:

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file("http://gvaonline.com.ar/eti/eti.xml",'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

foreach ($feed->ad as $item) {


  $linkTit  = $item->address;
  $imgLink  = $item->calle_nro;
  echo '<tr>';

  echo '<td>' . $linkTit . '</td>';
  echo '<td> '. $imgLink .'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';


}
```